# Accessing cells that aren't visible on a UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, swift2

All my cells have a switch that moves the cell to the bottom of the table. It works fine, however when there is enough cells to drop below the visible bounds, I receive the error that the cell doesn't exist. This doesn't work because I need to update ALL cells `sender.tag`.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell: TaskTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! TaskTableViewCell

        var task = tasks[indexPath.row]

        let index = tasks.indexOf(task)!

        cell.cellSwitch.tag = index
        cell.addSubview(cell.cellSwitch)
        cell.tag = index
        cell.cellSwitch.addTarget(self, action: "switched:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    return cell
}

func switched(sender: UIButton) {
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0)
let finalIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: tasks.count - 1, inSection: 0)

let task = tasks[indexPath.row]
tasks.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
tasks.append(task)
self.taskTableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, toIndexPath: finalIndexPath)

for var i = 0; i < tasks.count; i ++ {

let cellIndex = NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0)
let cell: TaskTableViewCell = self.taskTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(cellIndex) as! TaskTableViewCell
cell.cellSwitch.tag = cellIndex.row

}

}

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cellToBeReturned = UITableViewCell()

    if indexPath.row != tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0) - 1 {
        let cell: TaskTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! TaskTableViewCell

        var task = tasks[indexPath.row]

        cell.cellFlatSwitch.removeFromSuperview()
        cell.currentStreak.removeFromSuperview()

        switch(task.icon) {

        case "heart"?:
            task.color = colors[0]
        case "meditate"?:
            task.color  = colors[1]
        case "leaf"?:
            task.color  = colors[2]
        case "run"?:
            task.color  = colors[3]
        case "muscle"?:
            task.color  = colors[4]
        default:
            task.color  = .blackColor()
        }

        switch(task.icon) {
        case "heart"?:
            cell.pretickButton.setImage(Icons.imageOfHeartIcon, forState: .Normal)
        case "meditate"?:
            cell.pretickButton.setImage(Icons.imageOfMeditationIcon, forState: .Normal)
        case "run"?:
            cell.pretickButton.setImage(Icons.imageOfRunIcon, forState: .Normal)
        case "leaf"?:
            cell.pretickButton.setImage(Icons.imageOfLeafIcon, forState: .Normal)
        case "muscle"?:
            cell.pretickButton.setImage(Icons.imageOfMuscleIcon, forState: .Normal)
        default:
            cell.pretickButton.setImage(Icons.imageOfLeafIcon, forState: .Normal)
        }

        if task.longestStreak >= 21 {

            cell.starImage.alpha = 1

        } else {
            cell.starImage.alpha = 0

        }

        if localSettings.habitPreview == "dayCounter" {

            cell.currentStreak = LTMorphingLabel(frame: CGRectMake(11, 29, 39, 31))
            cell.currentStreak.morphingEffect = LTMorphingEffect.Anvil
            cell.currentStreak.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            cell.currentStreak.text = String(task.consecutiveDays!)
            cell.addSubview(cell.currentStreak)
            cell.streakSublabel.textAlignment = .Center
            cell.currentStreak.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            cell.streakSublabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            cell.growthPreviewImage.hidden = true
            cell.streakSublabel.hidden = false

        } else {

            if task.growth > 0 && task.growth <= 21 {
                cell.growthPreviewImage.image = UIImage(named: "growth\(task.growth!)")
            } else if task.growth <= 0 {
                cell.growthPreviewImage.image = UIImage(named: "growth1")
            } else if task.growth > 21 {
                cell.growthPreviewImage.image = UIImage(named: "growht21")
            }

            cell.growthPreviewImage.hidden = false
            cell.streakSublabel.hidden = true

        }

        if task.consecutiveDays == 1 {
            cell.streakSublabel.text = "day"
        } else {
            cell.streakSublabel.text = "days"
        }

        cell.taskLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        cell.taskLabel.text = task.name
        cell.taskLabel.textColor = task.color
        cell.cellFlatSwitch = AIFlatSwitch(frame: CGRectMake(300, 15, 70, 70))
        cell.cellFlatSwitch.lineWidth = 2.3
        cell.cellFlatSwitch.strokeColor = task.color!
        cell.cellFlatSwitch.trailStrokeColor = task.color!

        let index = tasks.indexOf(task)!

        cell.pretickButton.tag = index
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell.addSubview(cell.cellFlatSwitch)
        cell.tag = index

        cell.bringSubviewToFront(cell.pretickButton)
        cell.pretickButton.addTarget(self, action: "switched:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        cell.sendSubviewToBack(cell.cellFlatSwitch)

        if task.doneToday == true {
            cell.cellFlatSwitch.selected = true
            cell.pretickButton.alpha = 0.0101
        } else {
            cell.cellFlatSwitch.setSelected(false, animated: false)
            cell.pretickButton.alpha = 1.0
        }

        cellToBeReturned = cell

    } else {

        let cell: AddNewTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("add") as! AddNewTableViewCell
        cell.tag = indexPath.row

        cellToBeReturned = cell
    }

    return cellToBeReturned
}
```

Any tips or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since cells are reused, you can't assign tags to cells that simply don't exist.

Comment: are you assigning tags on `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: Problem is that you are trying to assign tag to cells according to your tasks.count, but that much cells doesn't exist, as cells are reused, so you are getting that error, Exactly what you want to do?

Comment: Yes I am assigning tags on `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. The animation works and the cells move but then cells titles start changing and duplicating as I scroll. I'm not sure what is causing this.

Comment: @SyedAliSalman Yes I am assigning on `cellForAtIndexPath`

Comment: then why don't use `reloadData` after changing position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong.

Don't call methods with `NSIndexPath` object references to move cells around.  The implementation of `UITableView` suggests you should use **one data source** (could be an array, a dictionary, a custom `NSObject`, `NSFetchedResultsController`, etc) to implement all the relevant `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` delegate methods and you make updates to your data source **first** then call either `reloadData` or `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` on your `UITableView` whenever you need to refresh your view.

In your case, I would simply use 2 `NSMutableArray`'s, one for items with, one for without tags.  Your switch handler should retrieve the item from the cell index path and move it from one array to the other.  Then you can call `beginUpdates` and move your cell appropriately.

They key is to make changes to your data source first and in a way that is consistent to your `UITableViewDataSource` methods, especially the `cellForAtIndexPath` method.  Basically the error you get is most likely because your data source is out of sync with the visible cells.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for that. But how will I know which index to move within the array without the `indexPath.row`?

Comment: you use a structure for your data source that makes sense to reflect how your data is presented.  there are lots of ways you can do that.  keep track of your array item indexes would be one way.

Comment: it also depends how you implement your switch handler method.  one way is to call the parent view of your `UISwitch` to get the `UITableViewCell` and then you call `UITableView.indexPathForCell:` to get the index for your data source.  let me know if it doesn't make sense to u.

Comment: Can I just use the `UISwitch`'s `.tag` (which is set to `indexPath.row` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function) rather than calling the parent view? I'm not sure how to call the parent view.

Comment: check out **View Hierarchies and Subview Management** https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW1

Comment: basically you call `UIView.superview`... all views already have references to others from their hierarchy.  you just need to read the documentation to know how it's implemented

Comment: Hey, I updated my code for more context. If you could read through it and tell me more specifically what I should do, it would mean so much. Thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: @exotue i can't do that... if you ask something specific i can try to help u